# Equivalent in python of package.json and "npm install --save" command to easly save every new package

Tags: python, installation, package

I'm looking for a way to install and manage all packages used in my python project in similar way `npm` does with `package.json` file and command `npm install --save`. I need it to install and save it file so I can later revert it.
I would expect something like `pip install --save` and file `pypackages.json` . I don't need `pip install -r packages.txt` but soemthing to save while adding new packages.

Comment: There is no answer for how to install package and at the same time save it to file... only how to install form a file

Comment: Check the accepted answer on the referenced question. It teaches how to freeze your current packages. I have a feeling that you come from node.js background. The python packaging system is kinda broken and has a learning curve. Just have a look at the answer and google about virtualenv.